# How do we capture the events in Tagging console?

Tags: aem, jcr, jackrabbit

I need to capture the events for tagging in CQ. Need to capture the tags whenever the users add/remove/change/delete tags in CQ tagging console.

I have an idea to implement a workflow & launchers to handle the event handling in tagging console. Whenever such event occur, automatically the workflow will get trigger and get the events. I don’t know how to implement such workflow. Please share any url related to this.

Also I heard that JCR listener, Is this helpful to manage event handling?

Please share if you have come across any requirement ?

Comment: What do you mean with Tagging console? Anyway, Event capturing isn't that complicated, it just has a few pitfalls, just implement the javax.jcr.observation.EventListener

Comment: Tagging console is where we create new tags. Is there any sample code for EventListner?

Comment: Have a look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27541429/3737177 just set the path to "/etc/tags"

Answer (score 0):

I would also use a workflow model with an appropriate launcher, as you suggested.

The launcher is actually quite easy to create - you can specifiy the location to watch (probably /etc/tags), the type of event (node creation, update, deletion) and the workflow to be triggered.

For workflow model creation, adobe has some articles here:
http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/workflows/create-models.html